# command line argument with usage message

Tags: linux, shell

I am having a lot of trouble using a command line argument in a script file to check if a file is being entered in the command line. So basically I have a script file named ./file and a logfile named log. I have an if then else statement to run a check to see if the right file is entered and if not the program exits with an echo error. If the right file name is entered then it continues to run script. I either get an error directory or file doesn't exist or my echo error no matter what I do. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for any help provided. I am using putty. this is what I have

```
  if ["./file log"]
      then
            echo ""
  else
            echo "error"
            exit 0
  fi
```

Comment: Are you saying that you should run the script with `$ ./file log`, i.e. with `log` as the argument? Your script seems to reference `./file` instead of `log`?

Comment: Yes  I'm sorry I changed it

Comment: that isn't unix shell syntax. are you trying to write a unix shell script?

Comment: I'm using vi linux

Comment: i think i've heard of that one - sounds old.

Comment: if there's only one "right file" possible. why even take an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to (self-)reference the script itself. You know it must exist. You just need to see if the `log` file exists. Hence, use the `-f` test ("FILE exists and is a regular file"). See `man test` for more information (`test` is essentially equivalent to `[...]`).

```
if [ -f "log" ]
  then
    echo ""
  else
    echo "error"
    exit 0
fi
```

If the `log` file is to provided by the argument when calling the script (e.g. `$ ./file log`), then you can refer to the first argument with `$1`. Hence,

```
if [ -f "$1" ]
```

Comment: WOW that was it. I feel like a complete idiot. Thank you!! If I may ask what is the $1 stand for???

Comment: You can refer to the each provided argument with `$1`, `$2`, etc. in order. You can also refer to all with `$@` and find the number of provided arguments with `$#`, which might both be useful for error-checking.

Comment: I can't thank you enough my head is hung in shame

Comment: We all had to start somewhere. It might be worth you seeking out some basic scripting resources though. These are relatively basic constructions in *nix land. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You must want this too. $0 is the name of the script, and $# the number of arguments. Additional notes, by default a script returns 0 on success, and <> 0 on error

```
#!/bin/bash 
    display_usage() { 
        echo "This script must be run with ...." 
        echo -e "\nUsage:\n$0 [arguments] \n" 
    } 

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    display_usage
    exit 1
fi
.... script ....
exit 0
```

Comment: Yup.  And then you'll want to run sanity checks on the arguments, and *still* echo your error/usage if things aren't right.  Once everything is "correct" THEN you start processing, etc.